# Create Outlook Task Request from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, outlook

I'm looking for a way to create Outlook Task Request from ASP.NET. I'm using Exchange Server 2003 for email server. Basically, user of my ASP.NET application will do something that will create Outlook Task based on some logic. Is this natively supported in .NET or must I use third party component?

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebDav for Exchange. [Here](http://blog.downtownsoftwarehouse.com/2006/10/26/using-net-and-webdav-to-access-an-exchange-server/) is an example how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Outlook with an Exchange Server? If so, you can use Exchange Web Services.

Exchange Web Services are an easy way of doing pretty much anything within an Exchange mailbox, so if you're going to be doing more than just Outlook Tasks, then it may be worth looking at. Otherwise, AFAIK, there are no native .Net classes (that ship with the framework).

I have also not seen any 3rd party components out there so far...

Comment: I'm using Outlook with Exchange Server, I'll revise the question.